# How to convert Blob to UploadedFile (primefaces) in java?

Tags: java, database, primefaces

I get `Blob` from the database and want to convert it to `UploadedFile` because I want to create a user (String user, String pass,... UploadedFile photo).. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to create user with File or Blob field, isn't it? In all situations you should use `InputStream` or `byte[]` (byte array) like adapter between all storage classes. [In Apache Commons library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) there are many useful methods to work with blobs, file etc.